force gcc to call function by absolute 64 address (x86_64)
As the title suggest I need gcc to generate call instructions to absolute 64 addresses. (it always uses relative 32 addressing for obvious reasons)
I also need it to happen only for specific functions.
An attribute or something would be handy, but i'm unable to find any.
I've already found the large addressing mode (with -mcmodel=large), but it modifies every call.

Ah, you mean have a function called by its absolute address always?

Best I could think of was to use a macro to force a call through a pointer.

@Jester I need something like
movabs rax, 0x0; call rax;

without any dereferencing instructions

Yeah that's doable with a macro, but depending on optimizations it may involve a memory access.

Can you maybe force calls to that function to go through the GOT, like gcc -fno-plt does for calls to shared library functions?  Then the call instruction would be call qword ptr [foo@GOTPCREL + RIP] (in GAS Intel syntax).  If that GOT entry is typically hot in cache, that's probably better than mov reg, imm64 / call reg.

How to execute a call instruction with a 64-bit absolute address?

Could you explain why you want this?

Write a wrapper function that does an absolute jump to your function.  The wrapper should be written in assembly in an assembly source file:
func_wrapper:
        movabs $func, %rax
        jmp    *%rax

Then, have your code call the wrapper instead of the function in question directly.

I need it to be inline and without any overhead.

@Meh Then I'm not sure if what you are looking for is possible with gcc without further concessions.  You could do it with inline assembly, but then you would need to disable the red zone (or alternatively work around it) at a slight performance penalty.  Perhaps you could give some context on your problem so other solutions for your underlying problem (that you try to solve by an absolute call) can be evaluated.

I'm making an opengl self modifying loader.
I made a program which reads relocations (from a COFF object) and writes them to an object so they can be used, and the problem I'm facing is that the opengl32 64 bit library get's loaded at a far address and I can't represent it as a relative 32 value. I've tried changing the load address of the program to be closer to the library, but the shared library doesn't get loaded at it's LDA and it makes me think it's not deterministic (it worked, though).

@Meh What's your problem with just doing an indirect function call?  The overhead is very low in this case and that's how this sort of problem is usually solved by shared libraries.  The address is resolved into a variable and the function called indirectly through said variable.
